# How do I validate stormpath jwt tokens?

Tags: node.js, stormpath

EDIT: It turns out that the stormpath tokens expire in 4 seconds. Does anyone know how to change this?

I have a REST API written using nodejs. I am using stormpath to manage my users.

I first ask the users to generate a JWT token which I do using stormpath.authenticate. And all the requests to the API thereafter are authenticated using this token. However I can't quite figure out how to authenticate the requests using stormpath.

When I try to call stormpath.authenticateApiRequest I always get a token expired error.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Authenticating a user:

```
app.authenticateAccount(request, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    callback(err);
  }
  callback(null, result.getAccessTokenResponse());
}
```

The token is sent back in the REST response. However the token I get is only for 4 seconds. An example token:

```
{ iss: 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/327amCVmifPJe3hr09BbiX',
  sub: 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/327S85vQ0qSth0raGDZwHN',
  jti: '5c0eb388-b9d4-4303-a9f3-b50ec9c35440',
  iat: 1443702904,
  exp: 1443702908 }
```

Comment: Hi there, could you post some example code to show us how you're using these methods?  That would help us debug.  I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com), feel free to contact us via support@stormpath.com if you cannot share code publicly.

Comment: @robertjd added some code and a sample jwt token

Comment: Ack, one more question: what versions of our libraries are you using?

Comment: "stormpath": "^0.12.2"